# mysql- cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

When I am trying to add foreign key constraint to the course table mysql said:

> ## 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
create table course
(course_id      varchar(8), 
 title          varchar(50), 
 dept_name      varchar(20),
 credits        numeric(2,0) check (credits > 0),
 primary key (course_id),
 foreign key (dept_name) references department
    on delete set null
);
```

The ddl statement I used to create the table department is:

```
create table department
(dept_name      varchar(20), 
 building       varchar(15), 
 budget             numeric(12,2) check (budget > 0),
 primary key (dept_name)
);
```

I have used `set foreign_key_checks=0` before creating any table.
The `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` says:

```
Syntax error close to:
```

> on delete set null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the column name in the foreign key definition:

```
foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/695282) is a SQL Fiddle.

Note that the `check` constraint is parsed, but not enforced.  MySQL accepts the syntax but does nothing.

Comment: in which rdbms, the sql statements would have worked?

Comment: I don't think any database would take the foreign key like that.  Most databases support `check` constraints both syntactically and enforce them.